# OutOfBoundsException. Where to put Bounds-Checking?

Tags: java, runtime-error, maze, indexoutofboundsexception

Where do I put bounds checking so that program generates an entire maze?
The code should print a Grid with a maze drawn by breaking walls between Cells. However, much to my dismay, the Grid stops when it reaches index 0 or  24. I need the program to visit every cell before it stops (if it goes to a border, it moves back).

Here is the previous error that I'm getting:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: -1
        at Grid.genRand(Grid.java:73)
        at Grid.main(Grid.java:35)
```

And here is the source code:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Component;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Grid extends Canvas {

    Cell[][] maze;
    int size;
    int pathSize;
    double width, height;
    ArrayList<int[]> coordinates = new ArrayList<int[]>();

    public Grid(int size, int h, int w) {
        this.size = size;
        maze = new Cell[size][size];
        for(int i = 0; i<size; i++){
            for(int a =0; a<size; a++){
            maze[i][a] = new Cell();
            }
        }
        setPreferredSize(new Dimension(h, w));
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Frame y = new Frame();
        y.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        Panel r = new Panel();
        r.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        Grid f = new Grid(25, 400, 400);
        r.add(f, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        y.add(r, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        f.genRand();
        f.repaint();
        y.pack();
        y.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(450, 450));
        y.setVisible(true);
    }

    public void push(int[] xy){
        coordinates.add(xy);
        int i = coordinates.size();
        coordinates.ensureCapacity(i++);
    }

    public int[] pop(){
        int[] x = coordinates.get((coordinates.size())-1);
        coordinates.remove((coordinates.size())-1);
        return x;
    }

    public int[] top(){
        return coordinates.get((coordinates.size())-1);
    }

    public void genRand(){
        // create a CellStack (LIFO) to hold a list of cell locations [x]
        // set TotalCells = number of cells in grid  
        int TotalCells = size*size;
        // choose a cell at random and call it CurrentCell 
        int m = randomInt(size);
        int n = randomInt(size);
        while(m<1){
            m = randomInt(size);
        }
        while(n<1){
            n = randomInt(size);
            }
        Cell curCel = maze[m][n];
        // set VisitedCells = 1  
        int visCel = 1;
        int o = 0;
        int p = 0;
        int h;
        int d;
        int[] q;
        // while VisitedCells < TotalCells 
        while( visCel < TotalCells){
            d = 0;
            // find all neighbors of CurrentCell with all walls intact
            if(m!=0&&n!=0){
                if(m<size&&n<size){
                    if(maze[m-1][n].countWalls() == 4)
                        {d++;}
                    if(maze[m+1][n].countWalls() == 4)
                        {d++;}
                    if(maze[m][n-1].countWalls() == 4)
                        {d++;}
                    if(maze[m][n+1].countWalls() == 4)
                        {d++;}
                }
            }
            // if one or more found 
            if(d!=0){
                Point[] ls = new Point[4];
                ls[0] = new Point(m-1,n);
                ls[1] = new Point(m+1,n);
                ls[2] = new Point(m,n-1);
                ls[3] = new Point(m,n+1);
                // knock down the wall between it and CurrentCell
                h = randomInt(3);
                switch(h){
                    case 0: o = (int)(ls[0].getX());
                            p = (int)(ls[0].getY());
                            curCel.destroyWall(2);
                            maze[o][p].destroyWall(1);
                        break;
                    case 1: o = (int)(ls[1].getX());
                            p = (int)(ls[1].getY());
                            curCel.destroyWall(1);
                            maze[o][p].destroyWall(2);
                        break;
                    case 2: o = (int)(ls[2].getX());
                            p = (int)(ls[2].getY());
                            curCel.destroyWall(3);
                            maze[o][p].destroyWall(0);
                        break;
                    case 3: o = (int)(ls[3].getX());
                            p = (int)(ls[3].getY());
                            curCel.destroyWall(0);
                            maze[o][p].destroyWall(3);
                        break;
                }   
                // push CurrentCell location on the CellStack 
                push(new int[] {m,n});
                // make the new cell CurrentCell
                m = o;
                n = p;
                curCel = maze[m][n];
                // add 1 to VisitedCells
                visCel++;
            }
            // else 
            else{
                // pop the most recent cell entry off the CellStack 
                q = pop();
                m = q[0];
                n = q[1];
                curCel = maze[m][n]; 
                // make it CurrentCell
                // endIf
            }
        // endWhile  
        }   
    }

    public int randomInt(int s) { return (int)(s* Math.random());}

    public void paint(Graphics g) {
        int k, j;
        width = getSize().width;
        height = getSize().height;
        double htOfRow = height / (size);
        double wdOfRow = width / (size);
//checks verticals - destroys east border of cell
        for (k = 0; k < size; k++) {
            for (j = 0; j < size; j++) {
                if(maze[k][j].checkWall(2)){
                g.drawLine((int) (k * wdOfRow), (int) (j * htOfRow), (int) (k * wdOfRow), (int) ((j+1) * htOfRow));
            }}
        }
//checks horizontal - destroys north border of cell
        for (k = 0; k < size; k++) {
            for (j = 0; j < size; j++) {
                if(maze[k][j].checkWall(3)){
                g.drawLine((int) (k * wdOfRow), (int) (j * htOfRow), (int) ((k+1) * wdOfRow), (int) (j * htOfRow));
            }}
        }
    }
}

class Cell {

    private final static int NORTH = 0;
    private final static int EAST = 1;
    private final static int WEST = 2;
    private final static int SOUTH = 3;
    private final static int NO = 4;
    private final static int START = 1;
    private final static int END = 2;
    boolean[] wall = new boolean[4];
    boolean[] border = new boolean[4];
    boolean[] backtrack = new boolean[4];
    boolean[] solution = new boolean[4];
    private boolean isVisited = false;
    private int Key = 0;

    public Cell(){
    for(int i=0;i<4;i++){wall[i] = true;}
    }
    public int countWalls(){
    int i, k =0; 
    for(i=0; i<4; i++) {
    if (wall[i] == true)
    {k++;}
    }
    return k;}
    public boolean checkWall(int x){
    switch(x){
        case 0: return wall[0];
        case 1: return wall[1];
        case 2: return wall[2];
        case 3: return wall[3];
    }
    return true;
    }
    public void destroyWall(int x){
    switch(x){
        case 0: wall[0] = false; break;
        case 1: wall[1] = false; break;
        case 2: wall[2] = false; break;
        case 3: wall[3] = false; break;
        }
    }
    public void setStart(int i){Key = i;}   
    public int getKey(){return Key;}
    public boolean checkVisit(){return isVisited;}
    public void visitCell(){isVisited = true;}
}
```

Comment: sorry for that, just being crazy here, needing a fix. I tried fixing my code but It still does not satisfy me since when it reaches an end, it stops instead of going out-of-bound.

Comment: I also thought of a try-catch statement... should I put the entire if in the try{}?

Comment: Your code force to look if index -1 or index 25 exist and of course it throws exception because there is no such array element. You can simply add check statement for if it is going out of bound or you can fix the program logic.

Comment: Good edit.  Down-vote removed.  Now I look at the question, some thoughts.  1) Don't mix Swing (e.g. `JFrame`) with AWT (e.g. `Canvas`) components. 2) Where does the `Canvas` ever draw anything?  For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/). 3) Please use a consistent and logical indent for code blocks. 4) Since the component has a preferred size, don't call `setSize()` on the frame, just `pack()` 5) A Swing GUI should be started (and altered) on the EDT.

Comment: -will fix code blocks.
-can you elaborate SSCCE for me? I just post all the codes I used.
-the canvas, oh wait you're right. but since the main in this class is temporary, I forgot to put a panel holding the canvas. the complete program has a panel that holds the canvas.
-why can't I mix them? so I will replace all the swing components with AWT components?

Comment: just read what SSCCE means. thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

I overlooked you code very quickly:

1. you may got your exceptions while calling top() or pop() when coordinates is empty
   --> coordinates.get(coordinates.size()-1) if size is 0 you try to adress index -1 -> BAM!
2. some methods do look very complex. you may split that functionallity in separate methods/functions
3. you do not mix AWT and SWING components because the do behave different
4. NEVER EVER do GUI stuff (showing, hiding, changing content, clicking, whatever in JFrame, JPanel etc.) out of the Event Dispatcher Thread (EDT) -> this may cause dead locks